# custom checkbox with enable disable and selected in android

Tags: android, checkbox, selector, checked, disable

This is my simple selector

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_blue_border_unselected" android:state_checked="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_checkbox_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_blue_border_unselected" />
</selector>
```

When i add  **state_enabled : false/true**  it says, 
*"This item is unreachable as the previous item is more general match"*
...i donot understand why it is so? since i am also adding a new property -> state_enabled...i was thinking it will be like if both properties are matched then only select the respective drawable.

I want to do something like,

```
checked && not disabled -> blue color checked box,
not checked && not disabled -> blue border unchecked box,
checked && disabled -> gray color checked box,
not checked &&  disabled -> gray color unchecked box
```

And, checkbox.setEnabled(false) is not working for this case. This is my xml code.

```
<CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:button="@drawable/selector_chkbox_blue_border"
                        android:textColor="@color/steel_grey"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="Checkbox text"/>
```

I also tried this, but still not able to make it work:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_blue_border_unselected" android:state_checked="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_checkbox_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_checkbox_selected_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_blue_border_unselected_disabled" />
</selector>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'checkbox.setEnabled(false) is not working'?

Comment: i want to give a grey look to checkbox when it's disabled. And when I make checkbox as enabled false, its not changing the look. Checkbox becomes non-clickable which is correct, but does not change the color

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_checkbox_selected" android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_blue_border_unselected_disabled" android:state_checked="false" android:state_enabled="false"/>


    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_checkbox_selected_disabled" android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_blue_border_unselected" />


</selector>
```

This works, a default drawable will not have any states, other will have both the states...

Answer (score 0):

Add item with `state_enabled : false/true` before the item with no options, here it is `<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_blue_border_unselected" />`

As this item has no condition, it applies for every item and it overrides all the items below it because Android checks it serially, from top to bottom, like `if-else if` condition, when it finds a match, it stops.

So, in order to work, you have to add the item with no option at the last option.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_blue_border_unselected" android:state_checked="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_checkbox_enabled" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_blue_border_disabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_checkbox_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_blue_border_unselected" />
</selector>
```

Comment: i did this, but still its not working...


`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_blue_border_unselected" android:state_checked="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_checkbox_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_checkbox_selected_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_square_blue_border_unselected_disabled" />
</selector>`

Comment: @SamratGarai what is the error actually? adding the same text snippet doesn't help here.

Comment: There is no error as such, my only problem is, that I am not able to make the checkbox as gray color when it's disabled and also, I didn't know the text snippet will not get proper formatting so I updated the question again...